# Index out of bound when using Math.floor function

Tags: java, android, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a function, named it `scalling` with parameters are multidimensional array called `array`, integer `width` and `height`. Give assume that `array` have length of 640x480 and `width` also `height` 50 and 120. When I running my function, it gave me error index out of bounds when length 640 and index = 248million. Can someone help me, please??

here is my code:

```
private int[][] scalling(int[][] array, int width, int height){
    int m = array.length;
    int n = array[0].length;
    int[][] G = new int[height][width];
    double sy = height / m;
    double sx = width / n;

    if (sy > sx){
        sy = sx;
    }else{
        sx = sy;
    }

    for (int i=0; i<height; i++){
        double y = i/sy;
        for (int j=0; j<width; j++){
            double x = j/sx;

            int p = (int) Math.floor(y);
            int q = (int) Math.floor(x);
            int a = (int) (y-p);
            int b = (int) (x-q);

            if ((q==n) || (p==m)){
                G[i][j] = array[p][q];
            }else{
                double intensity= (1-a) * ((1-b) * array[p][q] + 
                        b * array[p][q+1]) + 
                        a * ((1-b) * array[p+1][q] + 
                        b * array[p+1][q+1]);
                G[i][j] = (int) intensity;
            }
        }
    }

    return G;
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and paste in the stack trace for the exception from logcat. 248million is not accurate enough.

Comment: There is no purpose to using Math.floor on x and y. They are ints. They cannot possibly have a fractional value. Using Math.floor there doesn't break things but it doesn't do anything useful either.

Comment: `height / m` and `width / n` are integer divisions and will never return a non-integer result. Cast at least one argument to `double` (e.g. `((double) height) / m`)!

Comment: sorry, I forget the exact number for the index. And I use double for x and y before, it was 248million when I use double, and also when I use int, it still same as before

Comment: So as I requested, post the stack trace.  It will show us the exact numbers.

Comment: it said that java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=639; index=2147483647

Comment: For starters, 2147483647 isn't  248 million. 2147483647 is the maximum Integer value. It may have resulted from a floor() of the double value Infinity which results from a division by zero. Your code is absolutely broken. Start with fixing the division height / m.

Comment: So you are trying to read the 2147483647th element of an array with 639 entries?  i think you need to go back to basics.  As laune says, your code, and understanding of arrays, is fundamentally broken.

Answer (score 1):

A division of two int's_

```
double sy = height / m;
double sx = width / n;
```

to return a double must cast to double *before* division is done:

```
double sy = (double)height / m;
double sx = (double)width / n;
```

Otherwise, zero or some other erratic value is stored in the double.

```
double y = i/sy;
        double x = j/sx;
```

Using 0.0 in sx or sy results in the double value "positive Infinity".

```
int p = (int) Math.floor( y );
```

This produces your "248million".

**Later** Also suspicious...

```
 if ((q==n) || (p==m)){
       G[i][j] = array[p][q];
```

Given these settings:

```
  int m = array.length;
  int n = array[0].length;
```

the above array access results in an index out of bounds. You can only access up to array.length-1.

**More**

```
sx = sy = Math.min(sx, sy); // prefer this to an if statement.
```

This is hardly correct:

```
int p = (int) Math.floor(y);  // p biggest integer below y
int q = (int) Math.floor(x);
int a = (int) (y-p);          // y-p is a fraction in [0,1.0) and so a = 0, always
int b = (int) (x-q);
```

So, a and b are always 0.

**Later** This produces what I think could be right. Note that width and height must be chosen to match the dimensions of the `int[][] array`, e.g., if this is int[4][4], width must be equal to height, or if it is int[4][6] we must have width:height = 3:2.

```
private static int[][] scaling(int[][] array, int width, int height){
int m = array.length;
int n = array[0].length;
int[][] G = new int[height][width];
double sy = height / m;
double sx = width / n;

sx = sy = Math.min( sx, sy );

for (int i=0; i<height; i++){
    double y = i/sy;
    for (int j=0; j<width; j++){
    double x = j/sx;

    int p = (int) Math.floor(y);
    int q = (int) Math.floor(x);
    double a = y - p;
    double b = x - q;

    if( q == n-1 || p == m-1 ){
        G[i][j] = array[p][q];
    } else {
        double intensity= (1-a) * ((1-b) * array[p][q] + 
                    b * array[p][q+1]) + 
                    a * ((1-b) * array[p+1][q] + 
                    b * array[p+1][q+1]);
        G[i][j] = (int) intensity;
    }
    }
}
return G;
}
```

Comment: it works to eliminate my "248million" :D, but it still out of bounds, what should I do next?

Comment: Read stacktraces. It shows the line, it shows the values... - See updated answer.

Comment: but i use the 'p, q, a, b' to get the difference between 'y' and 'p' and it my mistake to use 'int', but i'd tried using 'double' for these variables and use integer casting to access'array[p][q]' so it's like 'array[(int)p][(int)q]' but it's still show error message

Comment: What are you trying to compute? Have you got a link to the definition of the algorithm?

Comment: I use like bilinear filtering method to scaling my array multi-dimensional. But of course I edited it. You can check the original algorithm in here [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_filtering)

Comment: OK, I've corrected your code and I think it works, considering the caveats I've added in my updated answer.

Comment: thanks for your help, it works when i erase this line `sy = sx = Math.min(sy,sx)`, if I use that line, it still give me the same error with before

Comment: Strange. It worked with the data I used and it does the same as your if statement.

Comment: Really?? I don't know why it was like that on me, and FYI I dont use my if statement either. I just use the first `sy` and `sx`

Comment: So why is this in the code of your question: `if (sy > sx){ sy = sx; }else{ sx = sy;}`

Comment: I use that code to make the scale for height and width use same scaling number, if `sy=0.5` and `sx=0.4` it will use the `sy` and `sx` 0.5